# Why are $\max(x_i)$ and $\min(x_i)$ sufficient statistics for $\operatorname{Unif}(a,b)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

Suppose I have $X_i \sim \operatorname{Unif}(a,b)$. I have that the joint distribution is given by $$\frac{1}{\left(b-a\right)^n}\prod_{i=1}^n I(x_i \in (a,b)) = \frac{1}{\left(b-a\right)^n}I(\min(x_i) \in (a,b))I(\max(x_i)\in (a,b)).$$

Now, my question is why does this satisfy the factorization theorem? Don't $I(\min(x_i) \in (a,b))$ and $I(\max(x_i)\in (a,b))$ still depend on $a$ and $b$? If they don't, then don't we also have that $\prod_{i=1}^n I(x_i \in (a,b))$ doesn't depend on $a$ or $b$, and so, we can factor the original joint distribution as required, without any sufficient statistic.

I think I am misunderstanding something about sufficiency here.

Comment: The vector of original samples $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ will always be a sufficient statistic, by definition. It is more interesting to see if something simpler [than the full sample] contains all the "information" that the sample has regarding the parameter.

Comment: Review the factorisation theorem. You would find that the joint density $f(\mathbf x;\theta)$ factors as $f(\mathbf x;\theta)=g(\theta, t(\mathbf x))h(\mathbf x)$ for some $g$ and $h$ where $g$ depends on $\theta=(a,b)$ and on $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ through $t(\mathbf x)=(\min x_i,\max x_i)$ and $h$ is independent of $\theta$.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confused about the factorization theorem: if you can factor the

$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n ; \theta) = \phi(T;\theta)\cdot h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$$

then $T$ is sufficient for $\theta$.  The idea is that you can factor it into two pieces:

- one that depends on only the statistic and the parameter(s)
- one that depends only on the data and not the parameter

For your example, $h = 1$, which is independent of $\theta$ and $\phi$ depends only on $\max\{x_i\}$ and $\min\{x_i\}$.